# Image texture video clip wont cycle, pauses after the original clip length ends

Tags: animation, node-editor, video

Having issues with this video texture. The original video file is a 3 second, 6 MB video clip. I had thought simply checking "cyclic" and "auto refresh" and setting the "frames" to anything reasonably longer than the original clip would do the trick. I have other objects in the scene with the same node set up and all that work fine and cycle throughout the timeline as expected.

Here is a clip of the issue.

https://imgur.com/a/UtU8naA

Blender file:

[image]

Comment: pls provide a blend file to reproduce your problem, thx

Comment: No problem, added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting "Frames" to longer than the length of the clip is what's causing the pause.
Set it to the correct number of frames for the complete clip and it will repeat when it reaches the end.

Comment: Hello thank you for the tip! I went ahead and plugged in the exact amount of frames but the video clip still stops after the initial playthrough. I made sure in Premier that the clip was 80 frames and rendered at 30fps, and that my scene settings in Blender also has 30fps as the timeline framerate.

Comment: Actually, it worked! I saved and reopened the file and that did the trick for some reason. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Consider marking the answer as Accepted so that others might find it if they need it.